# Remove overflow if accordion height is lower than max-height

Tags: jquery, html

I have used an accordion plugin, modified the CSS and the jQuery, and now I want to achieve the result as described in the title of this question. Basically, a simple question, how can I remove the scrolling tab, if the height of the content is smaller than the max-height?

```
.info_inside {
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Use `auto` instead `scroll`

```
.info_inside {
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

[w3schools: CSS3 overflow-y Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp)

Comment: That works well, thank you. Guess I just didn't refer to the HTML guides on overflow.